# Powershell - Create an XML with specific namespace

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to create this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SRP xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample.xsd">
```

..but while I know how to write the namespace using XMLWriter (eg:

```
$XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", 
"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", 
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

..I've been unable to do so in a variable:

```
[xml]$XML = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$Declaration=$XML.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",$Null)
$XML.AppendChild($Declaration)
```

I've tried various combinations of Namespacemanager but to no avail.. it seems a stupid question, but so far I've been unable to replicate it (short of using an here-string with the hardcoded XML and casting it as an XML of course, but I'd prefer to do it the 'proper' way :)

Thanks to everyone reading so far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a namespace manager for this. Just create the nodes/attributes with the correct namespaces and let the XML processor figure out where to put them.

For your example:

```
$x = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
$x.AppendChild($x.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",$null))

$node = $x.CreateElement("SRP")

$attr = $x.CreateAttribute("xsi","noNamespaceSchemaLocation","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
$attr.Value="schema.xsd"

$node.SetAttributeNode($attr)
$x.AppendChild($node)

$x.OuterXml
```

Comment: Worked perfectly,
the only very minor quirk is that the resulting XML has the xmlns:xsi and xsi:nonamespaceschemalocation inverted... and the application is complaining about the xml not being generated by a valid schema. (I know it's equivalent, so it's application fault in this case.. stil, if there' s work around this, that would be even better) Many thanks!